# netMQ 4.0 multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, zeromq, netmq

I have some problems with multi-threaded server based on `netMQ 4.0`. I tried to use `http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:mtserver`, but there is no context on `netMQ 4.0`.

I tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < workerCount; ++i)
{
    new Thread(() => Worker(connStr.Value)).Start();
}

//...
private void Worker(string connStr)
{
    using (var socket = new DealerSocket(connStr))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var msg = socket.ReceiveMultipartMessage();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

but I get error:

> NetMQ.TerminatingException: CheckContextTerminated

and yes, it is terminated.

How can I create context in `netMQ 4.0` or how can I create multi-threading server using `netMQ 4.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `.NET` version 4.0 or higher, the `Thread` creation approach is outdated and shouldn't be used in such way - if your `workerCount` is high enough and you aren't providing any scheduler logic, your performance could degrade significantly instead of benefit.

This you can do instead your approach using [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

1. You can easily replace your worker threads with [`LongRunning` tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx).
2. You probably should introduce the [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx#Canceling%20tasks) for your workers to stop them correctly.

So your code could be something like this:

```
/// field in your class
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

using (var clients = new RouterSocket(connStr.Value))
using (var workers = new DealerSocket())
{
    workers.Bind("inproc://workers");
    for (var i = 0; i < workerCount; ++i)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker
            , cancellationTokenSource.Token
            , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            , TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
    var prx = new Proxy(clients, workers);
    prx.Start();
}

private void Worker()
{
    using (var socket = new ResponseSocket())
    {
        socket.Connect("inproc://workers");
        while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
             //...
        }
        // Cancel the task and exit
        cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

To simplify it you can pass the `CancellationToken` as a parameter to your `Worker` method.

Answer (score 1):

correct solution:

```
using (var clients = new RouterSocket(connStr.Value))
using (var workers = new DealerSocket())
    {
        workers.Bind("inproc://workers");
            for (var i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
            {
                new Thread(Worker).Start();
            }
            var prx = new Proxy(clients, workers);
            prx.Start();
            }

private void Worker()
    {
        using (var socket = new ResponseSocket())
        {
            socket.Connect("inproc://workers");
            while (true)
            {
                 //...
            }
        }
    }
```